# Hide column in Grid at runtime

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a trouble about hiding columns in a Grid at runtime.

In a project I use a function that returns the configuration of a column in a Grid.
For take the list of my columns in the Grid I use this piece of code:

> var cmV = cmpGrid.getView();
>   var cmH = cmV.getHeaderCt();
>   var cm = cmH.getGridColumns();

The variable "cm" returns an array with the configured columns in the grid.

When I manually hide a column with the "column" option in the header Grid  with ExtJS version 3.4.1 I can get the property

> `hidden:true`

for the configured column.
But with ExtJS 6 the configured column doesn't include this property.

How I can  resolve this issue?

Thanks at all in advance,
Lorenzo.

**

### UPDATE

**
I have discovered this about my previous question.
With

> var cm = cmH.getGridColumns();

I can get the array of the columns in the grid.
Analyzing this array with Firebug I had found the subarray "config" that contains the properties required by the columns for the configuration.
However now this array doesn't reflect more the changed configuration of a column but the default configuration applied.
My first question is if this new behavior is a bug or not.
Because I have found this new behavior I have changed my code to get the properties of a column not from the subarray config but from the radix. However now the possible configurations are so much.
Now my second question is if there is a way to reduce or to have only the principal properties for type of columns in a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `grid.columns[index].setHidden(true)` ?

Or if you want to take the list of columns, how about reconfigure columns.

```
var tempColumns = [];

// "cm" returns an array with the configured columns in the grid
cm.forEach(function(e) {
    if (some conditions) {
        tempColumns.push({
            xtype: e.xtype,
            text: e.text,
            dataIndex: e.dataIndex,
            hidden: true,
            width: e.width,
            align: e.align,
            format: e.format
        });
    }
    else{
        tempColumns.push({
            xtype: e.xtype,
            text: e.text,
            dataIndex: e.dataIndex,
            hidden: e.hidden,
            width: e.width,
            align: e.align,
            format: e.format
        });
    }
});

grid.reconfigre(null, tempColumns);
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17lq

Comment: Hi @Yasuyuki Uno. Thanks for this reply. But I cannot construct my column configs in this way. I must construct the column config with properties setting at runtime by ExtJS.